# Unable to retrieve the very last item in endless scroll RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an endless Recycler View, which contains data from a online forum thread extracted using JSoup. The recyclerview will keep populating itself until the user reaches the last page. I want to inflate a "end view" once the user reach the last page and scrolls to the very last visible item but i am unable to retrieve it.

I tried using the getItemCount() and findLastVisibleItemPosition() from recyclerview linearlayoutmanager. It manages to get the correct size but the "end view" will be inflated at the bottom every time it loads the next page. It doesnt inflate when the user reaches the very last item of the last page.

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, final ArrayList<ReplyItem> recyclerReplyList, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.recyclerReplyList= recyclerReplyList;
    this.context = context;

    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                .getLayoutManager();


        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                           int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                        totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                        lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                        firstVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                        verylastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

                        if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {

                            if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();

                            }

                            loading = true;

                        }

                    }
                });

    }

}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {


    if(recyclerReplyList.get(position) != null){
        return VIEW_POST;
    }

    else if(position == totalItemCount){
        return VIEW_END_ITEM;
    }

}


 @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                  int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
    if (viewType == VIEW_POST) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.replies_row, parent, false);

        vh = new PostViewHolder(v);

    }

    else  if (viewType == VIEW_END_ITEM) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.end_item, parent, false);

        vh = new EndViewHolder(v);

    }

     return vh;
}
```

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Comment: @KishoreJethava Just tried it. It works! But it also triggers every time the user reaches the bottom of previous pages, before the next page loads. I have to put another condition on top of it. Thanks!

Comment: see updated answer. You can also mark answer as right one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***setOnScrollChangeListener*** but it will support on API 23 and above

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new View.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

            if (linearLayoutManager .findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition())
               //last item reached 

    });
```

**EDIT**

To identify scrolling direction use `scrollX` and `scrollY` of *onScrollChange*

```
if (scrollY == 0) { 
    // scrolled horizontally  
}
```

Comment: why are you using `View#setOnScrollChangeListener`? it will not work since `scrollX` and `scrollY` in most cases will have values of 0

Answer (score 0):

Try setting bottom margin to your recycler view!